# Retrieve a data from json ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

This is the content of dictionary *data

```
 Data =     {
        Specialities =         (
                        {
                ApprovalStatus = Unapproved;
                CurrencyCode = "<null>";
                Packages = "<null>";
                Photos = "<null>";
                ServiceDescription = 356563;
                Speciality = 22;
                SpecialityName = "Wedding Photographer";
                UserFRPs = "<null>";
                Videos =                 (
                                        {
                        VideoId = TWhSjpsGvPQ;
                        VideoLink = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWhSjpsGvPQ";
                        VideoType = YouTube;
                    },
                                        {
                        VideoId = N2CJrhHEydA;
                        VideoLink = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2CJrhHEydA";
                        VideoType = YouTube;
                    },
                                        {
                        VideoId = Lq6faQVYcwY;
                        VideoLink = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lq6faQVYcwY";
                        VideoType = YouTube;
                    },
                                        {
                        VideoId = v8WjMiodcKo;
                        VideoLink = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8WjMiodcKo";
                        VideoType = YouTube;
                    }
                );
            },
                        {
                ApprovalStatus = Unapproved;
                CurrencyCode = "<null>";
                Packages = "<null>";
                Photos = "<null>";
                ServiceDescription = 52454353;
                Speciality = 37;
                SpecialityName = "Hair and Makeup Stylist";
                UserFRPs = "<null>";
                Videos = "<null>";
            },
                        {
                ApprovalStatus = Unapproved;
                CurrencyCode = "<null>";
                Packages = "<null>";
                Photos = "<null>";
                ServiceDescription = 21212;
                Speciality = 55;
                SpecialityName = Transport;
                UserFRPs = "<null>";
                Videos = "<null>";
            }
        );
    };
}
```

This is the response i am getting from json, what logic should i write to retrieve "VideoId" linked to a specific "Speciality" (for ex- Speciality = 22)

if i write following code, i am getting all @"VideoId"

```
[[[[responseDictionary valueForKey:@"Data"]valueForKey:@"Specialities"]valueForKey:@"Videos"]valueForKey:@"VideoId"]
```

Comment: Specialities is an array, and every index is containing a dictionary.

Comment: you can use ObjectAtIndex for array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parsing way will be something like:

```
        NSDictionary *dataDict = [responseDictionary valueForKey:@"Data"];
        NSMutableArray *specialityArray = [dataDict valueForKey:@"Specialities"];
        NSDictionary *objectDict = [specialityArray objectAtIndex:your index (0/1/2)];
        int *speciality = [[objectDict ValueForKey:@"Speciality"] intValue];
    if(speciality = 22)
    {
        NSMutableArray *videoArray = [objectDict valueForKey:@"Videos"];
        NSDictionary *videoObject = [videoArray objectAtIndex:your index (0/1/2)];
        NSString     *videoID     = [videoObject valueForKey:@"VideoId"];
    }
```

Parse the rest accordingly as per your need.

Comment: Thanks for help Saad, your code solves my problem but the only issue is i cannot hardcode index.
        NSDictionary *objectDict = [specialityArray objectAtIndex:your index (0/1/2)];

Comment: do you really wana hardcode? we normally hardcode if we are dead sure of some value and its occurrence. And its a bad practice too.

Comment: I don't want to hardcode bcoz speciality id might change, so how to get the index of a particular specialityid

Comment: for that you can iterate through your specialities something like this:
  `for(NSDictionary * objectDict in specialityArray)
  {
 int *speciality = [[objectDict ValueForKey:@"Speciality"] intValue];
and so on.
}`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code,

```
    NSArray *wholeArray = [[responseDictionary objectForKey:@"Data"] valueForKey:@"Specialities"];
    NSArray *subArray = [[wholeArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Videos"];
```

subArray is get all the videos values, then you get single value use this code,

```
NSString  *videoID = [[subArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"VideoId"];
```

or you will get all videoID in single variable use this below code,

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < subArray.count; i++) {
        [tempArray addObject:[[subArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"VideoId"]];
    }
```

finally tempArray get All the VideoID values, anywhere you use,

```
NSString  *videoID = [tempArray objectAtIndex:0/1/2];
```

hope its helpful

Comment: Thanks for help Iyyappan But i cannot harcode the index